# problem in baking normal map in blender, connecting edges appear in normal map

Tags: uv, texture-baking, normal-map

I am a beginner, I am trying to bake normals for an object, after baking the normals normal map shows the connected lines. This is not happening for other objects, so I don't know what I did wrong. I am attaching UV map and baked normal map. enter image description here

[image]

this is the uv map

[image]

and this is my normal map

Answer (score 0):

Your baking doesn't seem to be using your UV map at all. Maybe you have 2 UV maps and have the wrong one selected?

Comment: if you are talking about the scale of the uv's in the image it is because I have cropped it, their position is exactly the same. if it is something else then sorry i am not understanding what you are saying can you explain?

Comment: the uv map on the two images doesnt seem to match, that might show that you have more than one uv map. you can check under the object data (green triangle) --> uv maps, see what you have there.

Answer (score 0):

It has been resolved, it seems I was making edges sharp and increasing the mean bevel in the low poly model which was causing the problem.